# Key Value pair Objective-C

Tags: ios, json, api

so I've been given a task of using a flickr API created by a lecturer, and we have to use it to populate a tableview of a particular user. I'm able to count the number of elements etc, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to actually call the image/photo element of the pair?

This is the code:

```
- (NSArray *) photosForUser: (NSString *) friendUserName
{
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.findByUsername&username=%@", friendUserName];
    NSDictionary *result = [self fetch: request];
    NSString *nsid = [result valueForKeyPath: @"user.nsid"];

    request = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=%ld&has_geo=1&user_id=%@&extras=original_format,tags,description,geo,date_upload,owner_name,place_url", (long) self.maximumResults, nsid];

    result = [self fetch: request];

    return [result valueForKeyPath: @"photos.photo"];
}
```

What is used to fetch the data:

```
- (NSDictionary *) fetch: (NSString *) request
{
        self.apiKey = @"26225f243655b6eeec8c15d736b58b9a";


        NSLog(@"self.APIKey = %@", self.apiKey);

    NSString *query = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@&api_key=%@&format=json&nojsoncallback=1", request, self.apiKey]
                       stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *queryURL = [NSURL URLWithString: query];
    NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: queryURL];
    if (!responseData)
        return nil;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *jsonContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

    if (!jsonContent)
        NSLog(@"Could not fetch '%@': %@", request, error);

    return jsonContent;
}
```

Can anyone give me any pointers on how I can actually call the image?

Much appreciated.

edit: this is an NSLog output of what's in the JSON array received from the flickr API.

```
latestPhotos (
    {
    accuracy = 16;
    context = 0;
    dateupload = 1397679575;
    description =         {
        "_content" = "<a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/photos/tanjabarnes/\">
    };
    farm = 3;
    "geo_is_contact" = 0;
    "geo_is_family" = 0;
    "geo_is_friend" = 0;
    "geo_is_public" = 1;
    id = 13902059464;
    isfamily = 0;
    isfriend = 0;
    ispublic = 1;
    latitude = "34.062214";
    longitude = "-118.35862";
    owner = "66956608@N06";
    ownername = Flickr;
    "place_id" = "I78_uSpTWrhPjaINgQ";
    secret = cc17afe1b3;
    server = 2928;
    tags = "panorama losangeles beverlyhills tanjabarnes";
    title = blahlbah
    woeid = 28288701;
}
)
```

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775625/nsinvalidargumentexception-reason-data-parameter-is-nil-in-uitableview-while-tr/23780731#23780731

Comment: thanks for the link, but I think i need to utilise what was given.

Comment: u get the invalid JSON, u pass the server in the wrong API, check that

Comment: Sorry i'm not really sure what you mean, can you explain? Cheers

Comment: ur coding is fine, but u were get the invalid response from server, would u like to check ur response copy ur result and paste in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu here and check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the URL of the image using the ids in your JSON array. Like this:

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
```

or

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg
```

or

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{o-secret}_o.(jpg|gif|png)
```

So in your example:

http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2928/13902059464_cc17afe1b3.jpg

Here's how you get to your images:

```
  NSArray *photos = [self photosForUser:friendUserName];
  for(NSDictionary *dictionary in photos) {
    NSString *farmId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"farm"];
    NSString *serverId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"server"];
    NSString *photoId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *secret = [dictionary objectForKey:@"secret"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.staticflickr.com/%@/%@_%@.jpg", farmId, serverId, photoId, secret]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    // Do something with your image here
  }
```

Reference: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

Comment: awesome that makes sense thanks, but I'm still unsure about how I actually "retrieve" the id/secret/serverID from the nsmutable array?

Comment: Object #0 in your array log is a dictionary.  Get it first, then use key paths.

Comment: that's the part I'm not sure about. I've got the code to combine the three ID's I just don't know how to actually get the ID's from the array.

Edit: just saw your edit, thanks mprivat. Just having a look now

Comment: Thanks for your assistance thus far, so I've had a look at the code and it makes sense, I've added it in, but every time I try and use it (i.e. NSLog) in the method, it just keeps looping and black screen? but when I do it in a different class method call it just returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: wow mprivat you are a legend, i really appreciate your assistance. If you're ever in Australia, you can have unlimited drinks.

Thanks for the clear description of how everything works as well. Makes sense now

Where I was going wrong is I kept trying to focus on calling a key and then an object forKey on an array, and it kept crashing. Thanks heaps

Comment: Careful, I might take you up on this offer! Good luck